# How can I divert wind which is flowing parallel to the wall into the house?

Tags: vent, ventilation

Situation:

The house is surrounded by other structures in a way that the the wind direction remains parallel-horizontal to the wall. There are a couple of windows on that wall, but amount of air passing through those two windows is very small. If an obstacle could be placed to divert the wind into the house then the air passing through the windows would be greater.

Questions:

- How can I divert the wind (air) which is flowing parallel to the wall into the house?
- Is there any design for a wind catcher which can be mounted on an exterior wall?

Comment: What do you mean by 'capture'? What wall? For what purpose?

Comment: You could use a plastic bag. However, captured wind will quickly grow bored, tired, and will soon fall asleep and stop moving about.

Comment: @DA01   Please excuse my language mistakes.Question edited.

Comment: https://www.google.com/images?q=yacht+wind+scoop

Comment: *A review on wind driven ventilation techniques* **Energy and Buildings** 40(8) 2008 1586–1604  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378778808000443

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the ideal solution would be to get casement windows. If the wind blows in both direction (at different times) you could go with a set of casements and open the applicable one:

[image]

Barring that, I think you need to rig up something that works the same say...perhaps a sheet metal 'vent hood' mounted at an angle. Or even perhaps just a piece of plywood.

Comment: casements will divert parallel winds that have a strong horizontal component.

Comment: @mike right...that's what the OP was asking for, right? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Quite likely, yes, but OP did not specify that the winds were horizontal, only that they were parallel.

Comment: @mike ha! Good point.

Comment: @DAO1 - Thanks. It was an absurd point, but a point none the less. :)